# How to replace text in AutoHotKey but iff. the needle matches the exact capitalization of the ReplaceText?

Tags: windows, unicode, autohotkey

### Code

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance, Force
#Warn
SendMode, Input
SetBatchLines, -1
SetWorkingDir, %A_ScriptDir%
StringCaseSense, 1

:*?:EmDash::—
```

---

### Explanation

My goal is to replace the text "EmDash" with —, but only if the text is spelt *exactly* as "EmDash", not emdash or any other spelling except exactly that. The code currently works for replacing emdash with —, but this is not my goal. I have tried to solve this by using "StringCaseSense, 1", but to no avail. If anyone knows the answer please share it here. I have not found the answer to this problem on any forum.

Comment: It would be helpful to read the documentation before asking. All of the hotstring options are clearly and concisely documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Option Case sensitive:](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Hotstrings.htm#C)**

> **C**: When you type an abbreviation, it must exactly
> match the case defined in the script. Use C0 to turn case sensitivity
> back off.

```
:c*?:EmDash::—
```